# Why can't I have docker running asynchronously w/ Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the workaround to getting both docker and Android Studio Emulator running?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: What OS are you using? If you are using VirtualBox - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168799/android-emulator-and-virtualbox-cannot-run-at-same-time

Answer (score 0):

I got Android Studio to work inside a Docker container, including device emulators. For this to happen, in addition to installation of several libraries, I had to ensure that the user inside the container belongs to both kvm and video groups by their gids in the host.

Scripts which build the Docker image and start the container can be found in: [Android Studio in Docker container](https://github.com/tddpirate/androiddocker)