# Unable to start emulator device in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, virtualbox, android-virtual-device

I got an error that avd device cannot launch. I have solution on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16168799/5241603), but cannot solve my problem. I though It may conflict with my genymotion, so I use command `killall virtualbox`. It said

`virtualbox: no process found`.

I use ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I use android studio v2.2.

I know it should not be ask, but I have no solution. Please help.

Here the message:

[image]

Comment: Sorry that may be wrong suggestion please go through @indramurari answer..

Comment: Thank @Ram. Let me try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly because you have either `VirtualBox` or `VMware` running on the same machine. The reason (at least that’s what I think) is that the kernel module of `VirtualBox` or `VMware` and KVM can’t take Advantage of Intel VT-x or AMD-V at the same time.

So Restart your system once. It should work

Comment: I don't know that it is so easy like this. Thank you. My problem solved.