# Why can't Genymotion and emulator run at the same time?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, android-studio-2.0

I am not able to run android wear emulator and genymotion at same time  as it gives me Error : 
Unfortunately, there's an incompatibility between HAXM hypervisor and VirtualBox 4.3.30+ which doesn't allow multiple hypervisors to co-exist.

Please  provide me proper solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is the only walk-around that i could find, basically you should use an EABI based android wear emulator to be able to run both (geny and wear) at the same time [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168799/android-emulator-and-virtualbox-cannot-run-at-same-time)

hope this helps you.

Comment: You can Flag a question as a duplicate rather than linking it to another question.