# Android Studio3.0 Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request

Tags: android, exception, android-studio-3.0

During making project,I always get an exception.

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.

In Gradle Console shows

> AAPT err(Facade for 20170267): error converting input arguments to UTF-8
>   Slave 20170267 failed to start
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at D:\sdk\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.0\aapt2.exe) are not corrupted.
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:211)
>       at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
>       at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   AAPT err(Facade for 10300771): error converting input arguments to UTF-8
>   Slave 10300771 failed to start
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at D:\sdk\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.0\aapt2.exe) are not corrupted.
>       at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:211)
>       at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
>       at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Workplace : Window XP, Android-studio3.0,JDK1.8.0

Does anybody have a solution, I would be very gratefull

Comment: Here check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002187/android-studio-3-0-runtimeexception

Comment: I had seen this solution,but it is based on linux,I use windowXP

Comment: @CheungChakBong did you solve it?

Comment: It looks like AAPT2 is having some issues running on your win32. Can you try running the aapt2.exe in your ANDROID_HOME/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.1, for example: "$ aapt2.exe compile -h"?